# Erroneous Field in jOOQ Record

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have 3 tables `A`, `B` and `C` which are part of an inheritance chain:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

and look like:

```
A(row_id)
B(row_id, a_row_id REFERENCES A(row_id))
C(row_id, a_row_id REFERENCES A(row_id))
```

Note that the column names are the same (`a_row_id`)

Now, I fetch `Record`s of `B` and `C` by doing:

```
ctx.select()
    .from(
        Tables.A
        .leftOuterJoin(Tables.B).onKey()
        .leftOuterJoin(Tables.C).onKey()
    )
    .where(someCondition)
    .fetch()
```

I join over both `B` and `C` because I don't (at this point) know which one I'm looking for.

But, when I know I need to fetch `B` and do this:

```
ctx.select()
    .from(
        Tables.A
        .leftOuterJoin(Tables.B).onKey()
    )
    .where(someCondition)
    .fetch()
```

I get a `Record` on which if I do `record.field(Tables.B.A_ROW_ID).toString()`, I get `"b.a_row_id"`, and if I do `record.getValue(Tables.B.A_ROW_ID)` I get the expected value.

However, If I do `record.field(Tables.C.A_ROW_ID).toString()`, I get `"b.a_row_id"` and `record.getValue(Tables.C.A_ROW_ID)` gives me the expected value of `record.getValue(Tables.B.A_ROW_ID)`.

I think this is happening because the column names referring to the parent table are the same.

Is jOOQ using only the field_name of the table (and not the fully qualified "table.field_name") if that is the only table in the join?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of [`Record.field(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#field-org.jooq.Field-), [`Record.field(Name)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#field-org.jooq.Name-), and [`Record.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#field-java.lang.String-) all follow the same, consistent logic:

In SQL, a record's column has a name. That name can be qualified if it originates from a table / view (in a schema (in a catalog)), but that is optional. Unqualified columns are perfectly fine too, e.g. when:

- Aliasing the column
- Creating expressions, such as `col + 1`
- Using `JOIN .. USING`, in case of which columns are not qualified
- Using derived tables (which may have a table name, but certainly not a schema / catalog)
- Using `SELECT *` with vendor-specific, column-emitting operators like `PIVOT`, `MODEL`, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.
- Etc.

As you can see, from a syntax perspective, having qualified column names are the exception, not the rule. Thus, the most reasonable and generally useful implementation of [`Record.field(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#field-org.jooq.Field-) is to:

- Find the *exact* match inside of the record (fully qualified column name)
- If that fails, find the *approximate* match inside of the record (unqualified column name)
- If that is *"ambiguous"* (because top-level selects allow for such ambiguity), then:

  - [jOOQ 3.8+ logs a warning](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5046)
  - [jOOQ 4.0+ will throw an exception](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4455)

So, the behaviour you've observed is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Lukas already answered the main question but I just wanted to note to you that in the end jOOQ is running a SQL statement.  It's bounded for security and caching but it's still a SQL statement.  You can see the SQL itself if you turn up logging.
If you like the returning a dynamic record and you want column to be X you can always do .as("X") to make it easier to read the data back out.